# NoReverseMatch in Ajax Reorder

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I am running into the following issue while implementing an Ajax reorder view into my app. Essentially, my app is just a table that you can filter, reorder, and operate CRUD functions within. When I applied the filter view, the reordering doesn't work anymore.

You should be able to update the ranking of each row based on dragging the row up/down

ajax:

```
class AjaxReorderView(View):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            data = dict()
            try:
                list = json.loads(self.request.body)
                model = string_to_model(self.kwargs['model'])
                objects = model.objects.filter(pk__in=list)
                # list = {k:i+1 for i,k in enumerate(list)}
                for object in objects:
                    object.rank = list.index(str(object.pk)) + 1
                model.objects.bulk_update(objects, ['rank'])
                # for key, value in enumerate(list):
                #     model.objects.filter(pk=value).update(order=key + 1)
                message = 'Successful reorder list.'
                data['is_valid'] = True
            # except KeyError:
            #     HttpResponseServerError("Malformed data!")
            except:
                message = 'Internal error!'
                data['is_valid'] = False
            finally:
                data['message'] = message
                return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"is_valid": False}, status=400)
```

pick_list:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load cms_tags %}
{% block title %} {{ title }} · {{ block.super }} {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}    

<div style="font-size:24px">
  {{ title }}
</div>

<div style="font-size:14px; margin-bottom:15px">
  Click on the arrows on the right of each contestant and drag them up or down to reorder them based on how far you think they are going to go. 
</div>

<form method="get">
  {{ myFilter.form }}
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<ul>

<table class="table table-hover" id="table-ajax" style="background-color: white;">
  <thead  style="background-color: #de5246; color:white; border-bottom:white">
    <tr>
      {% comment %} <th></th> {% endcomment %}
      <th style="width: 50px; text-align: center;"></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Hometown</th>
      <th>Occupation</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Progress</th>
      <th style="width: 160px; text-align: center;">Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="order" data-url="{% url 'cms:reorder' model_name %}">
    {% include 'app/filter_list.html' %}
  </tbody>
</table>


{% endblock %}
```

filter_list.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load cms_tags %}



{% for order in orders %}

<tr id="{{ order.id }}">
    <td><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/files/{{ order.photo }}" width="50"/></td>
    <td><a href="" title="Leads" style="text-decoration: none">{{ order.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ order.hometown }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.occupation }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.age }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ order.age }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm border-0 reorder" title="Reorder">
            <i class="fa fa-sort text-secondary"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% empty %}
<tr class="table-warning nosort">
    <td colspan="100%" class="text-center"><small class="text-muted">No {{ model_verbose_name_plural|lower }}</small>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr class="table-light table-sm nosort">
    <td colspan="100%"><small class="text-muted">Total rows: {{ orders.count }}</small></td>
</tr>
```

urls

```
app_name = 'cms'

urlpatterns = [
    path('ajax/reorder/<str:model>/', AjaxReorderView.as_view(), name='reorder'),
]
```

urls2

```
...
    path('picks/filter/', week, name="week"),
]
```

views

```
def week(request):
    orders = Pick.objects.all()
    myFilter = PickFilter(request.GET, queryset=orders)
    orders = myFilter.qs
    context = {'orders':orders, 'myFilter':myFilter}
    return render(request, 'app/pick_list.html',context)
```

models

```
class Pick(models.Model):

    submitter = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Submitter', null=True, blank=True)
    week = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Week', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name', null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)
    #photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", max_length=500, verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Hometown', null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Age', null=True, blank=True)
    progress = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Progress', null=True, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Occupation', null=True, blank=True)
    elim_week = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Week Eliminated', null=True, blank=True)
    rank = OrderField(verbose_name='Rank', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_from_object(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app:pick-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pick'
        ordering = ['rank']
        verbose_name = 'Pick'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Picks'
```

error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/picks/filter/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account',
 'cms',
 'app',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django_cleanup',
 'bootstrap_datepicker_plus']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\templates\base.html, error at line 16
   Reverse for 'reorder' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cms/ajax/reorder/(?P<model>[^/]+)/$']
   6 :   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   7 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
   8 :     integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
   9 :     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
   10 :   
   11 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css"
   12 :     integrity="sha512-vKMx8UnXk60zUwyUnUPM3HbQo8QfmNx7+ltw8Pm5zLusl1XIfwcxo8DbWCqMGKaWeNxWA8yrx5v3SaVpMvR3CA=="
   13 :     crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
   14 :   <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">  
   15 :   {% block extracss %}{% endblock %}
   16 :   <title>{% block title %} Fantasy Bachelor{% endblock title  %}</title>
   17 : </head>
   18 : 
   19 : <body style='background-color:#e7e7e7;'>
   20 :   {% include 'include/navbar.html' %}
   21 :   <div class='row' style='background-color: #e7e7e7;'>
   22 :     <div class='column' style='padding-left:35px;padding-top:22px ;float: left; width:17%;background-color: #f1f1f1;'> 
   23 :       <ul class="nav flex-column">
   24 :         <li class="nav-item">
   25 :           <a class="nav-link" style="color:black" aria-current="page" href="#"><img src="{% static 'img/pick_icon.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1"></i>  Picks</a>
   26 :         </li>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\app\views.py", line 144, in week
    return render(request, 'app/pick_list.html',context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /picks/filter/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'reorder' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cms/ajax/reorder/(?P<model>[^/]+)/$']
```

Comment: It seems `model_name` is empty when passing to url tag in `pick_list`. At least I can not see if a value exists for this variable. This could lead to `('',)` arguments. Can you check if `model_name` has an actual value?

Comment: How would I check this? I think this is the issue as well, as it worked before adding the filters and does not afterwards. This leads me to believe it's filtered to nothing somehow

Comment: Just make sure that your view provide the correct model name to the template. Then your template can access it and Django can find an URL with reverse.

Comment: I guess wee() is your view to display the page. Then pass `model_name` via the context to the template: `context = {'orders':orders, 'myFilter':myFilter, 'model_name': Pick.__name__}`